# navigation bar poistioning rtl ltr

Tags: html, css, laravel, sidebar

i have a small problem with my side nav bar in ltr i made it responsive by adding a button to toggle and un toggle it and also i used media query to hide it if it is under 700px and only show the toggle button so that the user could press it and then the side nav will appear so that he could navigate and its style is the same as if it is more than 700 px keep in mind that i want it to be with its same style i don't want to converte it into top nav or smthg after that is explained this is the noraml view at more than 700px
[image]

but when i resize my window to be less than the full window scree of the desktop it looks like this 
[image]

in en version it still has the same width and all but in ar version as you can see it looks like this and the reason why this is happening is because of the poistioning in css the ltr version is by default poistioned to the left but in rtl it should be manually poistioned 
my css is too long so that i will only share the poistioning part if you want me to share it all it is ok but it might waste your time because as i said before its too long 
ar positioning css

```
  .page-wrapper.toggled .sidebar-wrapper {
    left:80%;

  }
```

en

```
.page-wrapper.toggled .sidebar-wrapper {
    left: 0px;
  }
```

working (expected resault but this one is on the left side i want it to be at the right side)
https://jsfiddle.net/r52nhfb4/2/
have the poistioning problem
https://jsfiddle.net/r52nhfb4/1/
keep in mind that i am using laravel so all the weird text and stuff are laravel syntax

Comment: i uploaded the code you can talk  a look

Comment: anyone ?  it has been more than 3 days

Comment: whether my answer works ?

Comment: Yeah it is working perfectly thanks a lot bro ^__^ and sry for the late reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change the below given css:

```
.sidebar-wrapper 
{ width: 260px; 
height: 100%; 
max-height: 100%; 
position: fixed; 
top: 0; 
right: -300px; /*change this */
z-index: 999; 
}

.page-wrapper.toggled .sidebar-wrapper 
{ 
right:0; /*change this */
}
```

check out my answer:https://jsfiddle.net/zLy8xhfb/